# Merge master functionality into shared branches in Git

Tags: git, version-control, merge, versioning, branch

Suppose that I have several shared branches on my Git repository, for example: *newfeature*, *experiment* and *gtkgui*, and I share those branches in the *origin* repository. My team and I make some changes on all branches and push those changes into the *origin* repository. Later I detect a minor bug on the core code, I fix it and commit it to the *master* branch.

I need this fix to be available on the other three branches. What is the best way to do this? Do I need to merge the *master* branch into the other branches one by one and push them? Could *git rebase* help me?

Answer (score 1):

The two solutions are topic branch and cherry-picking:
See "[Git & Working on multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334027/git-working-on-multiple-branches/1340143#1340143)".

Now I really **don't recommend cherry-picking**, which in your case would mean [duplicating a set of commits all over the place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312254/in-git-how-do-you-apply-a-commit-of-bug-fix-to-the-other-newer-branches/3312341#3312341) (i.e. in different branches).

So as long as you make changes from the oldest branch that needs them, and **[merge forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312254/in-git-how-do-you-apply-a-commit-of-bug-fix-to-the-other-newer-branches/3312341#3312341)**, you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just rebase the feature branches on the master when this happens (which I understand changes slowly, so that should not be a big deal). It also distributes resolving any ensuing inconsistency nearer the point in time where it arose (thus benefiting from a hot wet cache effect, hopefully). Or you could cherry-pick the change(s) into the feature branches, when merging later on git should notice the already applied changes and just omit them silently.